# Android Studio "Build - make project" does not create jar

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am developing an app in Android Studio for the first time, and I want the app to connect to a server that I will also develop. This server will run on the Java Runtime Environment instead of Android, but I'd prefer if I can develop it alongside the app, in the same project and IDE.

What I have done so far:

- added a `server` folder in the root (same level as the `/app` folder)
- added a `server/src/java/main/Hello.java` file to get started
- added a `server/build.gradle` file with this content:

  ```
  apply plugin: 'java'
  jar {
      manifest {
          attributes 'Main-Class': 'Hello'
      }
  }
  ```
- updated `settings.gradle` to include the server module like this:

  ```
  include ':app', ':server'
  ```

The above suffices to get this working:

- Executing `gradle build` on the command line now creates an executable server.jar.
- The server code shows up in Android Studio. It is also built if I click `Build - Make Project`.

However, `Build - Make project` is for some reason only compiling `Hello.java` files into a .class file. It is not creating the `server.jar` file. Why is it not doing the same thing as a `gradle build`? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

All available gradle tasks can be explored from the "Gradle projects" tool window on the right hand side of Android Studio, though you may have to click the "refresh" button first before it shows them. The jar task should show up there, and double clicking will build the server.jar file.

Creating a jar file is not necessary to quickly launch the server from Android Studio though. Change `server/build.gradle` as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "Hello"
```

After another refresh in the "Gradle Projects" tool window, this should make a "run" task available. Right-click it and click the "run ..." menu item to turn this task into a run configuration. Now the application can easily be started with the run button at the top of the IDE.